# change AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer position instantly

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer on screen. I want to change its position instantly after the user touches a button.

I am able to change its position using the following code, but it is not happening instantly but with some kind of smooth liner transition.

```
CGRect frame = self.preview.frame;
frame.origin.x = previewLeft;
frame.origin.y = previewTop;
self.preview.frame = frame;
```

How can I make it to change its position without any kind of intrinsic animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CALayer.frame` is a computed property, but it cannot be *explicitly* animated. By setting it, you're also setting `position`, which is *implicitly* animated.

You can temporarily suppress all actions, the mechanism by which Core Animation creates its default layer animations:

Swift code:

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)

self.preview.frame = frame;

CATransaction.commit()
```

Objective-C code:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];

self.preview.frame = frame;

[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Seems odd that one would work but not the other. I almost never mess around with `frame` when I'm at the CA level.

Comment: I don't think you're correct. Just because `frame` **triggers** an animation doesn't mean it's animatable. It's just a side effect, and in fact, `position` is what's being implicitly animated. I posted the documentation note in my answer.

Comment: There is a `frame` property. Just because it's a computed property doesn't make it less of a property...

Answer (score 1):

LucasTizma's answer is perfect.

Besides, there is a trick to solve this issue.

Just slow down the window speed:

```
[(CALayer *)[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0] layer] setSpeed:0.9];
```

Don't forget to correct it to `1.0f` after your transition.